# Optimize vector emplace_back

Tags: c++, optimization, stl, c++17

We have to find all points in a circle and keep it in a vector for plane fitting. We have written the following code for that. The number of points in the circle is around 2960520. When executed it takes about 300 ms for executing the `vec.emplace_back(t)`. Is there a way to optimize the code?

```
constexpr int radius = 971;
auto time_begin = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
int rSquare = radius * radius;
vector<Point_t> vec;
vec.reserve(2048 * 2048);
for (int i = 1024 - radius; i < 1024 + radius; ++i)
{
    int iSquare = (i - 1024) * (i - 1024);
    for (int j = 1024 - radius; j < 1024 + radius; ++j)
    {
        int y = j - 1024;
        if ((y * y + iSquare) <= rSquare)
        {
            Point_t t{ static_cast<double>(i),static_cast<double>(j) };
            vec.emplace_back(t);
        }
    }
}

auto time_end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

Structure declaration

```
struct Point_t
{
    double dX;
    double dY;
};
```

Comment: Try to avoid creation of a temporary `Point_t` object. I.e. `vec.emplace_back(static_cast<double>(i), static_cast<double>(j));` That's why `emplace_back()` function is for.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, you are right, I just missed the `reserve` line.

Comment: @Sprite Even without `reserve` my bet is that `vector` is quicker than `list` in this case. It won't do 2960520 dynamic allocations like a `list` is likely to do.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I get it, thank you.

Comment: Did you try allocating whole vector first, then processing it to help vectorization (simd usage on double-to-int conversion) by compiler? When I try your code on godbolt, it produces only mov commands in gcc 10.2 setting. Perhaps its just memory bottleneck because of predefined values since radius is constant so it produces values then just moves them to vector?

Comment: @ huseyin tugrul buyukisik : I do not understand your comment.. I do not not know exact number of points before hand

Comment: Why do you think it's `emplace_back` and not `reserve` along with the computation taking the time? Also, did you turn on compiler optimisations?

Comment: @rustyx : I removed emplace_back statement the execution time is about 12 ms

Comment: `emplace_back` is the only observable effect, without it the compiler probably optimizes away the loop entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you rethink the algorithm. You currently test all points in the area. Instead you could just use Pythagoras theorem to calculate the start-point and end-point for each line. You actully just have to calculate one quarter of the circle if you do it correctly.

While this would require the use of square root I think performing sqrt 'radius' number of times it's most likely much faster that testing `(2*radius)^2` points.

Sorry, no code. Don't have access to a C++ compiler at the moment.

Comment: You can even make it faster, by avoiding costly math operations altogether: [Midpoint algorithm implementation in C](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#C). Also, there is a [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) about this.

Comment: I used bresenhans algo first. There are several duplicate  points.  Removing  them is costly